# While Handling Multiple Threads..It is showing an error which i am not getting how to resolve

Tags: java, multithreading, multitasking

> Creating three threads to run parallely.

```
    class Thread1 extends Thread
 {
  Thread1(String s)
  {
 super(s);
 }
 public void run()
 {
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 System.out.println(getName());
 }
 }
```

> Second Thread

```
 class Thread2 extends Thread
{
 Thread2(String s)
 {
 super(s);
 }
 public void run()
 {
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 System.out.println(getName());
 }
}
```

> Third Thread.

```
 class Thread3 extends Thread
{
 Thread3(String s)
 {
 super(s);
 }
 public void run()
 {
 for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
 System.out.println(getName());
 }
}

class RunThread extends Thread
{
 public static void main(String... s)
 {
 Thread1 t1= new Thread1("Shalu");
 Thread2 t2= new Thread2("Neo");
 Thread3 t3= new Thread3("Shaleen");
 t1.start();
 t2.start();
 t3.start();
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
```

> This line below..i.e.Thread.currentThread.getName() is showing error;

```
 {
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread.getName());
 }
 }
 }
```

> The currentThread() is a valid method..then why it is howing error.

Comment: please format the code a little bit....

Comment: [`Thread.currentThread()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#currentThread()) is a method, not a field.

Comment: Neo indented his code perfectly well. Be like Neo! Indent your code well! :-)

Comment: Please check if the dupe actually answers your question, if it doesn't, ping me and I will try to help.